# Using tocloft getting chapter height problems

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

As shown in my MWE I'm using `tocloft` to add dots next to my chapters in the TOC. It works, but for a reason I don't know, the headings of the TOC, LOF, LOT are not on the same height as the regular chaptertitles anymore. MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
 \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
 \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{30pt}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
 \mainmatter
  \chapter*{Chapter without number}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter without number}
    Hello world!
  \chapter{Chapter with number}
    Hello world, again!
\end{document}
```

Does anyone has an idea why that's so and has a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tocloft` package, by default, discards customization made by other packages to how chapter titles are typeset, for what concerns the table of contents and the list of figures or tables.

In order to avoid this behavior, you have to load it with the `titles` option:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

---

Some comments about your code.

I would add `\hspace{\cftchapnumwidth}` to the unnumbered chapter entry.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Chapter without number}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hspace{\cftchapnumwidth}Chapter without number}

Hello world!

\chapter{Chapter with number}

Hello world, again!

\end{document}
```

You might want to avoid `\chapter*` and the clumsy `\addcontentsline` command with

```
\newcommand{\uchapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hspace{\cftchapnumwidth}#1}%
}
```

[image]

A more common trick that works without `tocloft` is typing `\protect\numberline{}` instead of `\protect\hspace{...}`; in this case it would add an unwanted period.

Comment: Ahh I maybe have ask my question in a misleading way. I want the actual headings of the TOC, LOF, LOT and the chapters to be on the same height, not the entries in the TOC itself. If you compile the MWE you should see that they are different. The TOC is a bit lower than the chapters. But your suggestions are also really helpful. :) Haven't noticed this yet.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I must have missed the `titles` option in the documentation. Is there a way to add the `\hspace{\cftchapnumwidth}` to the LOF and LOT? That would be great too.

Comment: @Chris.V I guess the correct parameters are `\cftfignumwidth` and `\cfttabnumwidth`