# overfull \vbox warning in table of contents, TOC doesn't break to a new page

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, fancyhdr, titletoc

I'm having the overfull \vbox problem in TOC. As you can see in the following image there is an overwrite on the footer. The warning I get is: "Overfull \vbox (188.96039pt too high) has occurred while \output is active". Ideally all the information of the toc should fit in two pages, but what I get is a first empty page with only the page number on it, and a second page which is the one I show in the image.I'm using xelatex.
[image]
Here it is my full cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{UniThesis}[]
% This document class is based on the 'book' document class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[oneside]{book}
% ============================================================================
% REQUIRED PACKAGES
% ============================================================================
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,hidelinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref} % Get nice PDF document links 
%\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks\do\-}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}      % Easily set margins
\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix}                 % Configure appendix formatting
\usepackage{tocloft}                                  % Configure ToC Lo{F,T} formatting
\usepackage{indentfirst}                              % Always indent first paragraph
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                 % Control header, footer position
\usepackage{graphicx}                                 % Include figures
\usepackage{setspace}                                 % Control spacing
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                         % Coding latin1
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                           % Spanish languaje
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, bbm}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[svgpath=./Images/]{svg}
\usepackage{color}                                    % Manage colors
\usepackage{breakcites}                               % Break citation reference
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption} % Customize caption of tables or figures
\usepackage{multirow}                                 % Allow multirow tables
\usepackage{float}                                    % Exact location of figures Here
\usepackage{enumerate}                                % Set item kind (I),(a),(A),...
\usepackage{subcaption}                               % Subcaption of subtables or subfigures
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{appendix} 
% ============================================================================
% NEW COMMANDS AND ENVIRONMENTS
% ============================================================================
% redefine plain to delete page number
\newcommand{\hackplain}{\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndice}  % appendix name
\appto\frontmatter{\pagestyle{plain}}       % pagestyle frontmatter
\appto\mainmatter{\pagestyle{fancy}}        % pagestyle mainmatter
\appto\backmatter{\pagestyle{fancy}}        % pagestyle backmatter

%\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}} % not number first page bibliography

% Environment to make a fancy dedication in the thesis
\newenvironment{dedication}{\phantom{}\begin{flushright}\begin{em}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\raggedleft}{\end{minipage}\end{em}\end{flushright}}

% Environment to make a list without indentation
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newenvironment{noindlist}
 {\begin{list}{\arabic{mycounter}.~~}{\usecounter{mycounter} \labelsep=0em \labelwidth=0em \leftmargin=0em \itemindent=0em}}
 {\end{list}}

% A command to control the line spacing
\newcommand{\newlinestretch}[1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}\normalsize}

% Input the specified file, and add a \clearpage afterwards
\newcommand{\inputfile}[1]{
    \input{#1} \clearpage
}


\newcommand{\addtotoc}[2]{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    #2 \clearpage
}


\addto\captionsspanish{ \renewcommand\contentsname{TABLA DE CONTENIDOS} }
\addto\captionsspanish{ \renewcommand\listfigurename{LISTA DE FIGURAS} }
\addto\captionsspanish{ \renewcommand\listtablename{LISTA DE TABLAS} }
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\bibname{BIBLIOGRAFÍA}}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}}

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\mbox{}}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftafterloftitle{\hfill\mbox{}}
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftafterlottitle{\hfill\mbox{}}


\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0mm]{\addvspace{1em}}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \ \thecontentslabel .\\ \quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[5pt]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.} \contentspage}
%\titlecontents{subsubsection}[22mm]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.} \contentspage}

% ============================================================================
% ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS
% ============================================================================
%\usepackage[letterspace=0]{microtype}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{ \bfseries \large }{\centering CAPÍTULO \ \thechapter }{0ex}{\centering }[\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\section}{ \normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesubsection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesubsubsection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}


% Set paragraph indention to 0.5 inches
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

% Make the ToC only show Chapters and Sections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% Make subsections get numbered
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% Setup the page format.  All headers are empty.  The center footer
% contains the page number.  Also, remove the headrule from all pages.
% Finally, use the 'fancy' page style (which uses all the things we
% just setup).
\lhead{\empty}
\chead{\empty}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{\empty}
\cfoot{\empty}
\rfoot{\empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Set the appendix to just have a letter not prepended by the main division
% number in the ToC (see the documentation for the 'appendix' package)
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\Alph{section}}

% Setup the ToC and List of {Tables|Figures|Whatever} to
% include the ellipses between the name and the page number.  Also make
% the page number big enough so that three digit numbers can be used.
\DeclareRobustCommand{\changetochap}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftchapfont\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
    \cftsetpnumwidth{1.5em}
%    \newgeometry{top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm}
}
\changetochap

% Do not enumerate page appendix title
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

To make a custom TOC I am using the following lines:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[0mm]{\addvspace{1em}}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \ \thecontentslabel .\\ \quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

    \titlecontents{section}[0mm]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}

    \titlecontents{subsection}[10mm]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.} \contentspage}
```

When I remove the line of subsection or the one of section, the warning disappears but obviously I lose the format I need. I have no clue why this is happening and hope you can help me!

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the comments, I have edited my main file so it can be reproducible:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{UniThesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter 
    \singlespacing               
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{fancy}}
    \tableofcontents \thispagestyle{fancy}\clearpage

    \mainmatter 

    \doublespacing 
    \input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
    \input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
    \input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
    \input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage


\end{document}
```

where randomtext.tex is:

```
\chapter{CHAPTER X}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{SECTION 1}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 1}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 2}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 3}
\blindtext[0]
\section{SECTION 2}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 1}
\blindtext[0]
\subsubsection{SUBSUBSECTION 1}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 2}
\blindtext[0]
\subsection{SUBSECTION 3}
\blindtext[0]
```

**EDIT2:**
The .toc file I get is the following:

```
\select@language {spanish}
\thispagestyle {fancy}
\pagestyle {fancy}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}CHAPTER X}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}SECTION 1}{1}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}SUBSECTION 1}{1}{subsection.1.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.2}SUBSECTION 2}{2}{subsection.1.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.3}SUBSECTION 3}{2}{subsection.1.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}SECTION 2}{2}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}SUBSECTION 1}{3}{subsection.1.2.1}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.1.1}SUBSUBSECTION 1}{3}{subsubsection.1.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}SUBSECTION 2}{4}{subsection.1.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}SUBSECTION 3}{4}{subsection.1.2.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}CHAPTER X}{5}{chapter.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}SECTION 1}{5}{section.2.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.1}SUBSECTION 1}{5}{subsection.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}SUBSECTION 2}{6}{subsection.2.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.3}SUBSECTION 3}{6}{subsection.2.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}SECTION 2}{6}{section.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}SUBSECTION 1}{7}{subsection.2.2.1}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.2.1.1}SUBSUBSECTION 1}{7}{subsubsection.2.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.2}SUBSECTION 2}{8}{subsection.2.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.3}SUBSECTION 3}{8}{subsection.2.2.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}CHAPTER X}{9}{chapter.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.1}SECTION 1}{9}{section.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.1}SUBSECTION 1}{9}{subsection.3.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.2}SUBSECTION 2}{10}{subsection.3.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.1.3}SUBSECTION 3}{10}{subsection.3.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3.2}SECTION 2}{10}{section.3.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.1}SUBSECTION 1}{11}{subsection.3.2.1}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {3.2.1.1}SUBSUBSECTION 1}{11}{subsubsection.3.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.2}SUBSECTION 2}{12}{subsection.3.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {3.2.3}SUBSECTION 3}{12}{subsection.3.2.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}CHAPTER X}{13}{chapter.4}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.1}SECTION 1}{13}{section.4.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.1.1}SUBSECTION 1}{13}{subsection.4.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.1.2}SUBSECTION 2}{14}{subsection.4.1.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.1.3}SUBSECTION 3}{14}{subsection.4.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4.2}SECTION 2}{14}{section.4.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2.1}SUBSECTION 1}{15}{subsection.4.2.1}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {4.2.1.1}SUBSUBSECTION 1}{15}{subsubsection.4.2.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2.2}SUBSECTION 2}{16}{subsection.4.2.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {4.2.3}SUBSECTION 3}{16}{subsection.4.2.3}
\contentsfinish
```

Comment: Please post working codes, not just a class. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Comment: this looks to me like the toc is being set in a box, or for some other reason it won't break to a new page.  (the overage of 189 points is *much* more than a couple of lines!)  nothing immediately catches my eye that might cause that, but that's what i'd look for.  is there anything at all on page 2 of the toc?

Comment: @barbarabeeton that is actually page 2 of the toc, page 1 is empty. Yes it doesn't break for some reason. How to debug it? I am using tocloft and titletoc packages, maybe the issue is around there?

Comment: if there's nothing (except a "contents" title) on page 1, then the actual list has to be in a box.  since i don't use either `tocloft` or `titletoc`, i can't be of much help, but there are lots of people here who are more familiar with those packages, and this may be a clue.  edit the information about what's on pages 1 and 2 into your question; that will kick it to the top of the list, where it will catch more attention.

Comment: The main source file is of little use if it includes other file we don’t have.  You should post an example that is both minimal and working, that is, that we can compile as it stands to reproduce the issue.  But I have another idea: you should have a file with extension `.toc`: try posting that file.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I have modified my main file to a simpler one. Also I have posted the .toc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `titlesec`, `tocloft`, **and** `titletoc` in the same class file. You should [include the option `titles`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134053/using-tocloft-getting-chapter-height-problems) when loading `tocloft`.

Compare the MWE (btw, your MWE is not really minimal)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0mm]{\addvspace{1em}}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \ \thecontentslabel .\\ \quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[5pt]{}{\thecontentslabel. \ }{}{\ \normalsize\titlerule*[5pt]{.} \contentspage}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{ \bfseries \large }{\centering CAPÍTULO \ \thechapter }{0ex}{\centering }[\bigskip \bigskip \bigskip]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\section}{ \normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesubsection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize \singlespacing \bfseries}{\thesubsubsection .}{2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\changetochap}{%
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftchapfont\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}%
    \cftsetpnumwidth{1.5em}
}
\changetochap

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage
\input{randomtext.tex}\clearpage

\end{document}
```

with the version where the second line is replaced by

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *why* the the inclusion of the option `titles` permits page breaks?  I noticed that, contrary to what it is stated in the documentation of the `titletoc` package, penalties items of 10,000 (or higher) are inserted between the lines of the ToC, in the OP’s example, not only when, say, a line for a subsection follows the line for a section (which is indeed desirable), but in all cases (_i.e._, between *all* lines).  This, however, does no longer happen when the `tocloft` package is invoked with the  `titles` option, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: my knowledge is limited. But my understanding is that `tocloft` clobbers a lot of the formatting by "doing its own thing in its own way", which makes it incompatible with many other packages that formats the TOC page. The `titles` option is included expressly to minimize this breakage. (In other words, my superficial knowledge is that whenever using `tocloft` with other things that also format TOC, one should always use `titles`.)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I should note that the current maintainer of `tocloft` [frequents TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson); I'm sure if you ask a question about the _technical_ aspect of how `tocloft` interacts with the TOC page and why/how the `titles` option help, he (or someone else) can probably answer it much better!

Comment: @WillieWong: Fair enough! (:-)  Maybe I’ll ask a question about this, as you suggest.  Thank you anyway!